# .net Satellite assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, localization

How can i create satellite assemblies in .net 3.5?
I have a nativetext.resx file in english and want to create assemblies for french and italian in different folders like

it --> nativetext.resources.dll
fr --> nativetext.resources.dll

is there any too like AutoLocalize.exe(am not sure)

Answer (score 1):

If you are editing a windows forms form, select the choosen form in the designer, set the `Localizable` property to **True,** and set the `Language` property to your choice. Then rewrite the text attributes for the controls. They will be placed in the appropriate resource file and  dll-s for each language will be generated.

The forms' language will reflect the OS' MUI setting, or you can change it programatically.

See: [MSDN Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289763%28VS.71%29.aspx), [MSDN Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28VS.71%29.aspx), [and more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1021kkz0%28VS.71%29.aspx) (mostly under the "localization" link). This is a complex topic, but simple things can be achieved simply.